# Serialize a struct/enum to bytes

Tags: serialization, rust

I'd like to serialize my struct to binary and de-serialize it on the other end of the pipe. Is there a way to achieve this with the serialize crate? It seems to only support JSON, hex and base64.

Comment: Can you elucidate on what you mean by “binary”?

Comment: A collection of u8, vector or array. I'm looking for something like Java's ObjectOutput/InputStream, essentially. Give it an object and it gives you bytes.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [bincode](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode)

Comment: @SBSTP: so, you don’t care what precise format it’s in?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan not really. What I want to do is send messages to another process via its `stdin`. I'd like to send serialized enums/variants through the pipe, and deserialize them on the receiving end. Basically, IPC using UNIX pipes.

Comment: … so something like JSON, while potentially suboptimal, is not untenable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [`bincode`](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode).

It provides `encode()` and `decode()` functions which operate on anything with `RustcEncodable` & `RustcDecodable` traits, which can generally be `#[derive]`d, and return `Vec<u8>`.

It has a few quirks (`isize` and `usize` become `i64` and `u64`, for example), but they are mostly there to improve portability and it tends to work as you would expect.