# Casting slice of values to a slice of bytes

Tags: vector, casting, rust

I am experimenting with an API where the callers provide a `Vec<Point>` which they want me to fill in with data. They can allocate room in the vector by creating it with `with_capacity` then push out its size by doing `push(Point{...})`. Then I will fill the underlying buffer with bytes from the disk, switch their endian representation as necessary, and then provide it back as a `Vec<Point>`.

Here is the function which takes their vector and fills it with data. The problem is that transmute only works when the types are of the same size, a `Point` is 12 bytes and transmute throws away 11 of those bytes.

```
fn read_points(&self, offset: u64, points: &mut [point::Point]) {
    let mut file = self.handle.borrow_mut();
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset)).unwrap();

    // bleep bloorp. danger!
    let points_buf : &mut [u8] = unsafe { mem::transmute(points) };
    file.read(points_buf).unwrap();

    // should take the 12 bytes and do the endian swaps
    for mut chunk in points_buf.chunks_mut(point::POINT_SIZE) {
        let point = point::buf_to_point(chunk);
        let buf : &mut [u8] = &mut chunk;
        point::fill_buf(buf, point.timestamp, point.value);
    }
}
```

Can this API be done in Rust or should I should I switch to doing safer but slower copy operations?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/28127165/155423 ?

Comment: Not quite, I don't want to change memory representation and bincode does not appear to give the in-place swap I want. I want to control how the values are read for endianness by borrowing a Vec<T> as a Vec<u8> (same total size for both), I want to do in place manipulation of the Vec<u8> in chunks and then go back to use the data as a Vec<T>. I need access to the underlying slice as if it were &[u8] temporarily to manipulate byte orders.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I wonder how you could be sure that there aren't padding issues - like if a 15-byte struct was actually padded to 16 bytes for storage reasons; every 16 bytes would be a piece of undefined memory...

Comment: Right, that's a good point. I think alignment will be OK and I'm pretty sure that the vector's backing array will store the values aligned one directly after the other. Also, I may need to force the representation of the struct to be `#[repr(C)]` so the struct is close packed.

Answer (score 5):

The memory representation of `&mut [T]` is `(*mut T, usize)` where usize is the number of `T` elements in the slice, not the number of bytes. So transmuting a slice of say 20 points gives you a slice of 20 bytes.

You have to compute the correct number of bytes:

```
let n_bytes = points.len() * std::mem::size_of::<Point>();
let points_buf = std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(points.as_mut_ptr(), n_bytes);
```

(Then of course deal of all the rest of the unsafety.)

Comment: Does this trigers a new memory allocation?

Comment: @user2284570 No, it doesn't allocate any new heap memory; it uses the existing pointer.