# How do I write an array of homogenous structs in Rust to a file that I can fread in C?

Tags: c, serialization, rust

Given an array of structs in Rust consisting of POD types, how do I write it to a disk file that can then be `fread()` in C code?

This would need to take into account any padding and packing necessary to allow `fread()` to succeed.

Comment: Not sure how or what Rust does in terms of structure packing but, though it may be inefficient, the *safest* way would be to write/read each structure member individually (a function to do so would be trivial). Note that, even between different C builds and/or platforms, structure packing may vary.

Comment: ... and there will potentially be issues with different endiannesses.

Comment: @AdrianMole: If you are careful to avoid any unnamed padding byte between your fields, and you declare your struct as `repr(C)` and you write in in Rust and read it in C in the _same architecture_, then maybe you can cast a slice of POD into a slice of u8 and write that to the file.

Comment: Can you expand on what went wrong with your starting attempt at solving this problem yourself?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to convert 'struct' to '&\[u8\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28127165/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: While converting a struct to a &[u8] is a meaningful part of the solution, it doesn't address the packing issues that would occur from writing an AOS, nor does it talk about writing the result to the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define your struct using the [C representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-c-representation).
2. Create an array of the structs.
3. Convert the array value to a `&[u8]` using unsafe code.
4. Write the `&[u8]` to a file.

```rust
use std::{fs, mem, slice};

#[repr(C)]
struct Datum {
    age: u8,
    height: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let data = [
        Datum { age: 0, height: 0 },
        Datum { age: 42, height: 99 },
    ];

    let p = data.as_ptr().cast();
    let l = data.len() * mem::size_of::<Datum>();
    // I copied this code from Stack Overflow and forgot to
    // document why it's actually safe and I probably shouldn't
    // use this code until I explain it.
    let d = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(p, l) };

    fs::write("data.bin", d).unwrap();
}
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const size_t ARRAY_LEN = 2;

struct Datum {
  uint8_t age;
  int32_t height;
};

int main() {
  FILE *file = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
  if (!file) {
    perror("Unable to open file");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  struct Datum data[ARRAY_LEN];
  size_t count = fread(&data, sizeof(struct Datum), ARRAY_LEN, file);
  if (count != ARRAY_LEN) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not read the entire array\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
    struct Datum *datum = data + i;
    fprintf(stderr, "age: %d\n", datum->age);
    fprintf(stderr, "height: %d\n", datum->height);
  }

  if (0 != fclose(file)) {
    perror("Unable to close file");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
$ cargo run -q
$ cc -Wall -pedantic main.c -o main && ./main
age: 0
height: 0
age: 42
height: 99
```

See also:

- [How to convert 'struct' to '&[u8]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28127165/155423)
- [What's the de-facto way of reading and writing files in Rust 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31192956/155423)
- [The bytemuck crate](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/)

> consisting of POD types

This term has no well-defined meaning in Rust. You will want to search for alternative terms.

Comment: good explanation: https://adventures.michaelfbryan.com/posts/deserializing-binary-data-files/